# Delete Item from DB using EntityCollection.Remove()

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have master table and details table. For example master table is `ObjectSet<'MasterObject>` and details table is `ObjectSet<'DetailObject>`. So each `MasterObject` contains `EntityCollection<'DetailObject>`.
As I understand I can remove `DetailObject` from database using following:

1. `EntityCollection<'DetailObject> ec = masterObject.DetailObjects;` 
   // as navigation property
2. `ec.Remove(deleting_detail_object);` // deleting_detail_object will be removed and marked for deleting.
3. `context.SaveChanges();` // I have exception

After `Remove()` the `deleting_detail_object.MasterObject` (navigation property) is `null`. It is normal. But `context.SaveChanges()` give me following exception :

> "The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because
>   one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a
>   change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is
>   set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values,
>   a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be
>   assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be
>   deleted."

I can delete this `DetailObject` using `context.RemoveObject()`, but is it possible to do it using `EntityCollection<>`?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this problem has something to do with EntityCollection, I think you have a problem with your database schema.
If your master table have a FK to details that is not nullable you cannot remove the detail table row since that would violate your database schema.

Either change it so that the FK can be null or redesign your database schema.

If this is an operation you need to support, maybe you should have a FK in your details table referencing your master table. So, that you can delete detail rows.

If this does not help please supply a script that shows how you create your database tables.

Comment: I have the following situation (...mmm very similar):

MasterTable:

id_master_object    (int primarykey) 
master_object_name  (nvarchar ...)

DetailTable:

id_detail_object     (int primarykey) 
id_master_object     (foreign key to MasterTable)
id_color             (foreign key to ColorsTable)


Two normalized tables with relation ... very simple and standard situation.

Comment: For example the following code works fine:

var deletingDetailObject = masterObject.DetailObjects.Single(s=>s.id_detail_object == ...);
context.DeleteObject(deletingDetailObject);
context.SaveChanges(); //fine, without exception

same tables, same project, same db ... i am surprised.

The relation between MasterTable and DetailTable is created automatically from existing db.

Comment: In my previous code example after EntityCollection<<'DetailObject>>.Remove(deletingDetailObject);
deletingDetailObject.EntityState was changed to Modified. Why not Deleted ? MSDN said: after Remove(...) deletingDetailObject will be marked for deleting.

May be it is wrong way (i mean entitycollection.remove()->context.savechanges())?
Thank you.

Comment: Please update your original post, and use code formatting. Also supply your the create scripts for your tables.